# SQL error: command not terminated correctly

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the follwowing query:

```
UPDATE o
SET o.supervisor  = e.supervisor
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN employees e on e.employee_id = e.employee_id
WHERE o.supervisor IS NULL;
```

The query is supposed to update the table orders when there is a null value in the column supervisor using the data from the table employees.

When I run this query (on DB visualizer), i get this error:
`ORA-00933: SQL-Befehl wurde nicht korrekt beendet`, what is german for

`ORA-00933: SQL-command wasn't terminated correctly`

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support `FROM` in an `UPDATE`.  You can use a subquery instead:

```
UPDATE orders o
    SET o.supervisor =
            (SELECT e.supervisor
             FROM employees e 
             WHERE e.employee_id = o.employee_id
            )
    WHERE o.supervisor IS NULL;
```

Note that your `JOIN` clause is wrong anyway, because it refers to only one table.

Comment: ah yeah it's o.emplyee_id = e.employee_id. But that was a typo in my question here.